# How to search a specific slack channel via the API

Tags: curl, request, postman, slack

I want to search a specific slack channel for a string. The docs are really unclear on this, even ChatGPT is lost (!)

It sais in the docs for search.messages:

> If more than one search term is provided, users and channels are also
> matched at a lower priority. To specifically search within a channel,
> group, or DM, add in:channel_name, in:group_name, or in:<@UserID>. To
> search for messages from a specific speaker, add from:<@UserID> or
> from:botname.

I have tried adding appropriate params both in the body of a post request and in query params for a get, with channel, channel_id and in:channel_name and none of them has any effect, I still get results from all channels

Answer (score 0):

Inside the get methods' *query* query param add the `in:channel_name` after a space. Example:

```
 ?query=<title> in:<channel_name> after:<date>
```